# Respond is not a valid script name, the name must end in .js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> 'respond' is not a valid script name.  The name must end in '.js'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: 'respond' is not a valid script name.  The name must end in '.js'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: 'respond' is not a valid script name.  The name must end in '.js'.]
>          System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetDebugName(String releaseName) +140
>          System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.ShouldUseDebugScript(String releaseName, Assembly assembly, Boolean isDebuggingEnabled, Assembly currentAjaxAssembly) +48
>          System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.DetermineResourceNameAndAssembly(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean isDebuggingEnabled, String& resourceName, Assembly& assembly) +106
>          System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlFromName(ScriptManager scriptManager, IControl scriptManagerControl, Boolean zip, Boolean useCdnPath) +77
>          System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlInternal(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip, Boolean useCdnPath) +370
>          System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlInternal(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip) +61
>          System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrl(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip) +123
>          System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterUniqueScripts(List`1 uniqueScripts) +167
>          System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts() +405
>          System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +145
>          System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) +9753946
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5054

I don't know where to even begin looking for the cause of this error
Happens when i debug my ASP.NET web app in VS2015.

It seems to have happened if I deleted `Global.asax` class because before that it would work locally but not when deployed to web when it threw type ambiguous errors.
I have now since re-added the `Global.asax` class, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

After adding

```
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

to `global.asax`, it's working again.

Answer (score 1):

See: [scriptreference named respond no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884640/scriptreference-named-respond-no-longer-works)

Check if you have a dependency on Respond.js (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), probably in site.master:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
         ...
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
         ...
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

If so make sure you include the files, you can add them using Nuget by searching for Respond, once you've done that you'll see Respond.js under the /scripts folder.

You may also need to Add a definition in Bundleconfig.cs inside RegisterBundles to point Respond to the scripts:

```
           ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition(
             "respond",
             new ScriptResourceDefinition
             {
                 Path = "~/Scripts/respond.min.js",
                 DebugPath = "~/Scripts/respond.js",
             });
```

Rebuild and run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was simple, my files were located in a folder managed by a cloud service (i.e. Google File Stream). I moved my files out and problem was gone.